# Choose DNS server for resolving hostnames in Java

Tags: java, dns, resolve

resolving a hostname to an IP address is rather easy in Java by using the *InetAddress* class like this:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com");
```

But this method uses the DNS server which is used by the running system.

Is there any way to specify the DNS server that should be used for resolving?

Comment: There are DNS libraries in Java, you can use them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use Sun Java, you can use this code:

```
//Override system DNS setting with Google free DNS server
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "8.8.8.8");
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
```

See this blog post: [How to set a custom DNS server with Java System properties](http://slackhacker.com/2010/07/21/how-to-set-a-custom-dns-server-with-java-system-properties/) for more details.

Comment: one question. If i resolve domain names fast (300 per Minute), is it heavy/allowed to (e.g Google DNS Servers) DNS Servers?

Comment: One potential problem is that this is global.

Comment: Running Oracle jre 1.8.0_111.  Prefer set the above properties via the command line (i.e. -Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1="dns,sun" -Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=8.8.8.8) so they are not buried in code and forgotten about.

Comment: On linux verification of which DNS server is being used can be done with *tcpdump -n 'udp port 53'*  And many java implementations only cache a DNS lookup for 30 seconds and it is often a good idea to extend this using the *sun.net.inetaddr.ttl* flag, for example *-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=1800* will not result in another lookup for a particular domain until 30 minutes has passed.